# Why Cmd showing erros while installing Kivy?

Tags: cmd, kivy

I am proceeding as steps given by [kivi](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html) and got stuck at step3.

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of the process here! Just referring to an external source is discouraged as the link most probably will become invalid somewhen in future, leaving behind a useless thread...

Comment: @JamesZ  I am new to stack overflow that is why this happened, also I didn't what you are trying to say here, Shouldn't i include links in my Questions?

Comment: There is a link in your question, so no idea what you're talking about. I removed the picture because it was the same text, but just small and hard to read.

Comment: @JamesZ is adding the picture same as the text what you are pointing

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command pip3 install kivy or you can see it here
https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/